# (бренд)ориентированный

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово "брендориентированный", слитно или через дефис?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Словари это слово не фиксируют. Поисковик выдает примерно одинаковое количество ответов по запросу бренд-ориентированный и брендоориентированный. В соответствии с существующими правилами, прилагательные, образованные от подчинительных словосочетаний (ориентированный на бренд) пишутся слитно. Какой вариант победит и будет закреплен словарями, поживем - увидим.

Comment: Если бы было две О, всё понятно: одна соединительная, и пишется слитно. А если О одна -- через дефис?